# Converting html with css and js code pages into a node js application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have multiple HTML pages with CSS and js files that work(if I open an HTML page on its own using chrome for example) I have tried to use these pages inside a node js project I created.
but for some reason, it doesn't recognize the js file and doesn't apply the CSS design.
I had installed path, but I still can't get node js to recognize the js file.
I'm referring to the js file inside the HTML code by

Comment: Node is backend server, it really doesn't understand the concept of HTML / CSS, that's the browsers side.  Node is often used for serving HTML / CSS but not consuming it.  I think you might be a little confused on what Node is meant to be able to do.  If you want to use Node js to create a native GUI app, that is possible.  But it's not just node, is usually a embeded browser with node in the back, eg.  Visual Studio Code is written in https://www.electronjs.org/ , basically a browser and nodejs glued together.

Answer (score -1):

You need to let the node know that you want to use these files in your project. Or you have to get permission to use these files from the node.

1. To do this, create a directory called 'public' in the root path of your project
2. And use the following code in the main file of your project

   ```
    const path = require('path');

    const express = require('express');

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
   ```

The above code means that any file in the public folder (such as js css img) is allowed to access and use